# Jquery Select all elements with both Class1 and Class2

Tags: jquery

I want to select all elements with both Class1 and Class2.

$(".Class1 .Class2") seems not to work...

Thanks!

Update in responce to comment:

I have the following html

```
<input class="Class1 Class2"/> 
<div class="Class1"/> 
<select class="Class2"/>
```

I want to only select the tags with both classes.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by inside?

Comment: @kralco626: What's your HTML code?

Comment: OK, question was edited - now some of the answers make sense. The title does not, though. `.find()` doesn't select elements with multiple classes.

Comment: I'll edit the title, i should have just stated what I wanted. But what would that selector return. I would assume that `$(".Class1")` returns a set with all tags that have Class1 and then `.find(".Class2")` looks in that set to find tags that have Class2, hence finally giving me a set with tags that have both classes...???

Comment: @kralco626: Nope, see [here](http://api.jquery.com/find/). The right command you'd use to do what you want would be `.filter()` instead. Sorry for jumping the gun and confusing everybody!

Comment: @Bolt - no problem, now i learned two thing! Thats what matters right? What set would `$(".Class1").find(".Class2") actually return?

Comment: @kralco: For something like `<div class="Class1"><span class="class2"></span></div>`, that would return the `span` because it's inside the `div`.

Comment: @Bolt - oh ya duh, i use that all the time, that was a brain fart to think that .find would work!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That should be as simple as this:

```
$(".Class1.Class2")...
```

Comment: please reformulate the question if this is not what you mean... I understand your question in exactly the same way

Comment: “I want to select all elements **with both Class1 and Class2**.”, so it’s okay

Comment: Bolt - "I want to select all elements with both Class1 and Class2" Sorry that my working of the question confused you...

Comment: This worked perfect. What was the selector returning when I had the space in there?

Comment: @kralco626: The same thing as `.find()` does, as I talk about in my comment.

Comment: @Bolt - gottcha. Thanks for the information guys! Either I need to use .filter, or have no space in between my classes in the selector.

Comment: Just thought I'd mention this interesting property that it is a commutative filter, meaning that the order inside the selector does not matter, whatever the order of classes in the class attribute of the element are.

Answer (score 9):

It’s basic CSS (notice the removed space):

```
$(".Class1.Class2")
```

It means: “Select all elements which have both classes”

With [the space character](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors) it means: “Select all .Class2 elements **inside** .Class1 elements”

Answer (score 2):

Initially, the way the question was put I misunderstood and said to add a comma in between the classes.

$(".Class1, .Class2")

This should work instead...  As you see others have already posted this solution.

```
$(".Class1.Class2")
```